# The apple watchkit app WKInterfaceTable > Row Controllers > Buttons action not working in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I am using WKInterfaceTable with some image, label and button, but when we tap on button then we are not able to fire the button event.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried things such as this:

First making sure you have a WKInterfaceButton of some sort like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceButton* actionButton;
```

or if you are trying to respond to taps in a table row you will need to implement  your interface controller’s table:didSelectRowAtIndex: method.

I'm not an expert and am just trying to think of logical steps that might help. You can try to look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html) link. They mention ways of doing things in Objective C as well so maybe it will help.